# deleting specific value of array

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array containing the numbers 1 to 10.
When i select one random array key, i want to delete this one
The following code does something like it, but just not good enough.

```
$imgArray = range(1,9);
$rand_key = array_rand($imgArray);
$imgValue = $imgArray[$rand_key];
unset($imgArray[$imgValue]);
```

The code deletes a value from the array, but it deletes the wrong one,
Echoing the array gives the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
)
```

Random selected item would be like number 4
but then it deletes array KEY 4, not array value 4..

Is there any way to change that? besides changing the variable(using -1)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As such there is no way to delete the unset the value by function but the You pay the trick for simplest function? Well, you won't find anything simpler.

```
$array=array(312, 401, 1599, 3);
$toDelete=401;

$array=array_diff($array, array($toDelete));
```

Answer (score 5):

[`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will return the key for the value that you search for, if it finds it:

```
$rand_key = array_rand($imgArray);
$imgKey   = array_search($imgArray[$rand_key]);

if ($imgKey !== false) {
    unset($imgArray[$imgKey]);
}
```

Of course you don't really need to do this, because `$rand_key` is already a key in the array ([`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) *returns a key*!) so the code reduces to:

```
$rand_key = array_rand($imgArray);
// optional, if you need the value for something:
// $rand_val = $imgArray[$rand_key];
unset($imgArray[$rand_key]);
```

Comment: This didn't really solve my problem.. What i am trying to do(and maybe should have mentioned) is echo 9 images on a random base, without duplicates, so thats why i have to delete the exact values in the array. So when i echo img4.jpg i want key 3(value = 4) deleted from my array

Comment: @SliQz: Well, why don't you simply [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array? After that you only need a bog-standard `foreach`.

Comment: Well thats because im still in the testfase. In the end ill have 36 different images, and i only want to display 9, one of wich is already known

Comment: @SliQz: `array_slice` after shuffling to keep only 9. If you keep explaining anyone can keep finding appropriate solutions, you should have done this in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing keys and values, that's why. *$imgArray* is a `range(1,9`) but that's values. Your keys are `range(0,8)`.

So *$rand_key* is actually not a random key but a random value.

Thus you delete the wrong... key and you're exposes to an OutOfBounds exception.

If you want to randomize searched values, the  use [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to retrieve and process the key

If you want to randomize searched keys, then use *range(0,8)*.

Comment: "OutOfBounds" exception in PHP? Not likely.

Comment: My bad. Index not found error, but you've got the point : still an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Create array
$imgArray = range(1,9);

// Get random key from array
$rand_key = array_rand($imgArray);

// Get key value from array
$imgValue = $imgArray[$rand_key];

// Delete value from array
unset($imgArray[array_search($imgValue,$imgArray)]);


Here is your array:
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
)

rand_key: 2

imgValue: 3

After delete imgValue: 3

New Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
)
```